# C# & IB API - Passing variable while one method has to be declared as 'void'

Tags: c#, api, output, void, interactive-brokers

**Background:** I am using the C# API of Interactive Brokers and Matlab to load financial data and to conduct an analisys on them. I am quiet used to coding in Matlab, but am at a beginner level with C#. I have created a dll file with all the respective functions to get market data and have implemented the libary into Matlab so that I can initiate the functions in Matlab.

**Current Issue:** Using Matlab I am calling a method *("top level method")* that is requesting the real time market data via the Interactive Broker API. Besides others the following method is called during the process, which simply writes the tickSize into the Console:

```
public virtual void tickSize(int tickerId, int field, int size)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tick Size. Ticker Id:" + tickerId + ", Field: " + field + ", Size: " + size + "\n");
    }
```

As far as my research has tought me, this method is declared as 'void', because no direct output variable is given back as the requested information is simply written in the console.

The problem is, that this method gets called via another more complex method within the IB API, which is also declared as 'void'.

**Goal:** I want to get the information of this method *(tickSize)* as an output when calling the top level method with Matlab.

**Constraint:** The method within the IB API calling 'tickSize' is also declared as a void method and is a complex C# method with many constraints and if clauses, which I would by all possibilities not like to modify on my own.

**Attempts to solve the issue:** I guess that the text book way to address this issue, would be to write a method defining the respective output type (for this example lets say 'int' if I only want to get the tickerId, then adjust the complex method of the IB API to also the same output type and last but not least to adjust the method posted above so that the variable can be passed on through the process. However, as outlined above I would not like to mess with the full trading API and was advised by the tech support of IB to write myself another 4th method which then could somehow save the output *(int tickerId)* and pass it on to the main method directly. Here is where my knowledge of C# certainly ended and also a long Google search did not seem to deliver any results for this specific issue.

**Question:** When having multiple levels of methods in C#, is there a way to overcome one method being declared as 'void' and send an output directly to the top level method?

*If it would help, I could also provide the respective methods I am talking about, but as I said the API one is quiet complex and I did not want to spam all the code in here*

Comment: I might be confused but you don't call tickSize, IB(gateway or tws) does.  When data that you have previously requested is available on the socket, the IB API will call this method for you.  It's asynchronous.

Comment: They may have meant to store the value in a class field or static property.

Comment: Yes, I am not calling tickSize directly, but as outlined by you it gets called by the IB API once the information is available. However, whenever this happens (in an ideal world) I would like tickSize to give me this information as an output variable to that I can keep working with it and not only post it in the command line. Hence, yes it should be stored in a list / class field or any object.

Comment: So then just make an assignment, or add to a list in the tickSize body.

Answer (score 0):

'public virtual void tickSize...' is a method called by an event within the API.

So, you don't call it, and nothing is 'returned'.  It is called automatically by the API and is the way in which the API provides you with data.

If you wish capture this data, the best method is probably along the lines of:

1. Create a tickSize class - attibutes: tickerId, field, size.
2. Create a class level List tickSizes list.
3. Inside the tickSize method you mention, instantiate a tickSize object, populate it with tickerId, field and size.
4. Add this object to the tickSizes list.

You will then have a list of tickSizes which you can use for your analysis.